# How can i increase the spacing between radio buttons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I can't find any way to increase the spacing between each radio button to match the format of my interface

[image]

this is my XAML code for the radio button

```
 <dxe:ListBoxEdit Name="xrbSplitFreight" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" FontWeight="Bold"  Grid.Column="8" Height="143" VerticalAlignment="center"  Width="218" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ShowBorder="False" Margin="0,0,0,7">
 <dxe:ListBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
     <dxe:RadioListBoxEditStyleSettings  />
 </dxe:ListBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
```

and this is how im populating the buttons

```
  private void InitSources()
    {
        List<String> source = new List<String>();
        source.Add("Split Freight");
        source.Add("Print Comment");
        source.Add("Do Not Split Freight");
        xrbSplitFreight.ItemsSource = source;
    }
```

I have tried numerous properties like padding and margin properties and it doesn't change the spacing.

Comment: where does `dxe:RadioListBoxEditStyleSettings` come from?

Comment: What is `dxe:ListBoxEdit`? Seems this is a non-standard list box control (looks like DevExpress). With the standard list box you can define your own item template with the desired spacing.

Comment: Yes, i am currently using DevExpress, and i haven't found a way to style it the way i want to.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is to increase the space between each radiobox and its text so it matches the space between the checkbox and its text above.

The problem here is that the radiobox content does not have a margin property to move it independently from the radiobox. Luckily in WPF you can encapsulate almost every control in any other control. So the solution, instead of using simple text, is to use a control that can display text and has a margin property like this:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="GroupName">
    <RadioButton.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Option 1" Margin="5 0 0 0"/>
    </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Margin` to add space between controls.

```
<RadioButton Margin="5"></RadioButton>
```

or

```
<RadioButton Margin="5,0,5,0"></RadioButton>
```

EDIT

Check this out.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="MyList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Margin="10" Content="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Each `RadioButton` is separated with margin given.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: where did you added the margin. can you show the code with margin.

Comment: <dxe:RadioListBoxEditStyleSettings Margin="10,10,10,10" />

Comment: edited the answer to show how normal `ListBox` with `RadioButton` works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is You're trying to place radio buttons inside of ListBox. Have You tried putting them into StackPanel with vertical orientation property? If You'll try You'll probably be able to set margins between them.

Comment: Doing that will not work with a dynamic number of items. It makes perfectly sense to use a list box here, imho.